# shared_ptr vs scoped_ptr

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, scoped-ptr

`scoped_ptr` is not copy able and is being deleted out of the scope. So it is kind of restricted `shared_ptr`. So seems besides the cases when you really need to restrict the copy operation `shared_ptr` is better to use. Because sometimes you don’t know you need to create a copy of your object or no. So the question is: besides the cases mentioned above, could we consider that `shared_ptr` is better (or recommended) to use instead of `scoped_ptr`. Does `scoped_ptr` work much faster from `shared_ptr`, or does it have any advantages?

Thanks!

Answer (score 72, accepted):

`shared_ptr` is more heavyweight than `scoped_ptr`. It needs to allocate and free a reference count object as well as the managed object, and to handle thread-safe reference counting - on one platform I worked on, this was a significant overhead.

My advice (in general) is to use the simplest object that meets your needs. If you need reference-counted sharing, use `shared_ptr`; if you just need automatic deletion once you've finished with a single reference, use `scoped_ptr`.

Comment: Mike, I couldn't agree more.  I always advise people to start with `boost::scoped_ptr`.  If you need transfer of ownership semantics (maintaining single ownership) then "upgrade" to `std::auto_ptr`.  If you need shared ownership only then do you use `boost::shared_ptr`.

Also, the `Boost.ptr_container` library is a nice alternative to containers of boost::shared_ptr when the elements don't really need to be shared.

Comment: As an aside: if you do need shared pointers, you can get rid of the extra allocations by allocating objects using `make_shared` or `allocate_shared` instead of `new`.

Comment: @David: I mostly agreed, but I'd skip `auto_ptr` entirely. It can't be used safely in standard containers, so it's likely to spring a few nasty surprises if you're not *really* careful.

Comment: Agreed, especially as auto_ptr is deprecated as of c++11, it shouldn't be recommended, instead I'd mention unique_ptr.

Answer (score 16):

**Performance** - `shared_ptr` has more functionality, but also requires an additional allocation (it's also larger, but that rarely matters).

[edit] The second allocation can be avoided by using `make_shared`, but then `weak_ptr` will hold the entire entire allocation even after the object is destroyed, which may be a problem for large objects.

**Expresison of Intent** using `scoped_ptr` you state more explicitly what you want to do. (In case you wonder - that's a good thing :) ). If you do this correctly, shared_ptr will also indicate "this object is intended to live beyond this scope"

Comment: +1 for expression of intent.  In that vein, `scoped_ptr` is very clear as is `shared_ptr`.  Likewise, use of `std::auto_ptr` should signal that you're willing to transfer ownership of the object at some point.

Answer (score 6):

Their intended purpose is different, so, in many cases "shared_ptr vs scoped_ptr" is not a question at all. Sure, you can use a shared_ptr when all you need is a scoped_ptr. But what's the point? shared_ptr has likely a slightly bigger overhead with all the reference counting involved.

Answer (score 3):

`scoped_ptr` works much faster from `shared_ptr`. It's right. `shared_ptr` always allocate memory using your allocator or default allocator.

Answer (score 1):

Scoped_ptr has little in common with shared_ptr, weak_ptr, or unique_ptr because it is only doing very special case of "reference counting". It isn't something you will need very often in well-designed code, but it is a good tool to have available.

Basically, a scoped_ptr isn't a reference-counted thing at all. Rather, it is an object you create on the stack (within the local scope) so that you can do something like this:

```
  //Some enclosing scope- anything set off by "{}" or even a function:
   {
       scoped_ptr<MyObject> ptr = new MyObject( parameters...);
   } // When we hit this closing brace, "ptr" will delete the "MyObject" inside.
```

You tend to see this pattern more with mutexes and other synchronization primatives- I can declare an "AutoLock" that will lock the mutex passed into it, then unlock it when it deletes to turn the whole "{}" scope into a critical section.

Also notice that a 'scoped_ptr' only ever makes sense when you can't just do a plain-old stack allocation like "MyObject obj(params..)" for some reason. After all, what it is doing is letting you use a heap-allocated object as if it was one on the stack. That tends to be a lot rarer a use case than the reference-counting of shared_ptr & its cousins.