# Returning C++ polymorphic objects (interfaces)

Tags: c++, oop, ownership

I'd like to know what is considered nowadays the **best practice** when returning a pointer to a polymorphic object from a function, for example when using factories. If I transfer the ownership, should I return `boost::unique_ptr<Interface>`? What should I return if I don't transfer the ownership (e.g. returning a reference to a member)? Is there an alternative, non boost-based way which is also commonly used? Thanks.

EDIT: it is supposed to be C++03 compatible, with a possibility to easily upgrade to 0x

EDIT2: Please note I'm explicitly asking about *common* approaches, best practices, and not just "a way to do this". A solution implying a conditional search-and-replace over the codebase in future does not look like a good practice, does it?

EDIT3: Another point about auto_ptr is that it *is* deprecated, whatever neat it is, so it looks strange to advertise its usage at the interface level. Then, someone unaware will put the returned pointer into a STL container, and so on and so forth. So if you know another somehow common solution, you are very welcome to add an answer.

Comment: You can complain all you want about how `::std::auto_ptr` is deprecated, the fact is you can't do any better without overhead, or narrowing the interface. If you use `::std::tr1::shared_ptr` you get reference counting when you don't need it.  Really `::std::auto_ptr` is the only reasonable solution available in C++. `::boost::unique_ptr` simply removes the problematic operations from `::std::auto_ptr`.  And while some might consider that better, it's a third-party library, and I couldn't recommend the use of a third party library as a 'best-practice' unless there was no alternative.

Comment: @Omnifarious: I appreciate you answer, but I'm also trying to encourage other people to share their opinion.

Comment: Is there some reason you are not considering `shared_ptr` for this?

Comment: @Zac: I don't mind considering shared_ptr, but I'd like to use a common solution. I.e. if many people use shared_ptr in interfaces and it is reasonable, I could also use it. I doubt that it is common, though, because shared_ptr is quite complex and has an overhead.

Comment: It really depends on what you are doing.  `auto_ptr` is a bad solution in several circumstances for several reasons (not even mentioning that it is deprecated) - for example, if you are storing the interface pointers in a collection, you can't use `auto_ptr`.  From the sounds of it, you are asking for a "best practice" that doesn't really exist.  How you approach the solution really depends on how you intend your factory method and the interface it returns to be used.

Comment: @Zac: You are right, and that's why I referred to `unique_ptr`, and not to `auto_ptr`. I just need to decide what to return from factory functions. I know the "old" way which you find in many books is to return raw pointers, and I'd like to know if there is a modern common replacement for that, taking care of the ownership problem.

Comment: In most cases, I find that 'shared_ptr` works well when returning from a factory.  It allows the object to take ownership of itself and maintains the ability to do things like operate on a set of these interface pointers.  The minor overhead of reference counting is not even noticeable on most systems (the exception being embedded systems - where you're likely to be using C instead of C++ anyway).

Comment: @Zac: Well, you can use shared_ptr anywhere where you could use unique_ptr, but the question is which one is more appropriate and common.

Comment: `unique_ptr` is fairly new (by comparison) so `shared_ptr` would be more common simply because of age.  But, like I said before, it will really depend on how you want to use the result of the factory method.

Comment: @Zac: You can convert an auto_ptr or a unique_ptr to a shared_ptr if you need it, so it seems more natural to return the simplest object. See here for some similar thoughts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770636/shared-ptr-vs-scoped-ptr

Comment: Using a `unique_ptr`, that isn't a big deal.  `auto_ptr` is anything but a "simple" pointer wrapper in that there are a lot of issues you have to be careful about when using them.  Use what you feel will meet your needs best.

Comment: @Zac Howland - I resent interfaces that force me to pay an unnecessary price.  If there is a good reason the interface should use `shared_ptr` apart from simple convenience, that's fine.  But if it's just convenience and a feeling that really, nobody should be caring about the cost except group X who we aren't targeting this at anyway, that means I'm a member of group X regardless of whether or not the implementor thinks I ought to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `::std::auto_ptr` for now, and when C++0x is available, then switch to `::std::unique_ptr`.  At least in the factory case where you are handing ownership back to the caller.

Yes `::std::auto_ptr` has problems and is ugly.  Yes, it's deprecated in C++0x.  But that is the recommended way to do it.  I haven't examined `::boost::unique_ptr`, but without move semantics I don't see that it can do any better than `::std::auto_ptr`.

I prefer the idea of upgrading by doing a search and replace, though there are some unusual cases in which that won't have the expected result.  Fortunately, these cases generate compiler errors:

```
::std::auto_ptr<int> p(new int);
::std::auto_ptr<int> p2 = p;
```

will have to become at least like this

```
::std::unique_ptr<int> p(new int);
::std::unique_ptr<int> p2 = ::std::move(p);
```

I prefer search and replace because I find that using macros and typedefs for things like this tend to make things more obscure and difficult to understand later.  A search and replace of your codebase can be applied selectively if need be (`::std::auto_ptr` won't go away in C++0x, it's just deprecated) and leaves your code with clear and obvious intent.

As for what's 'commonly' done, I don't think the problem has been around for long enough for there to be a commonly accepted method of handling the changeover.

Comment: +1 -- `std::auto_ptr` is awesome despite people bashing it all the time.

Comment: Well, but how do I switch to it then, by search-and-replace all over my code?

Comment: @7vies: Assuming the boost dependency isn't a problem just continue using boost, except where you must transfer ownership. Otherwise you're going to have to do the search and replace.

Comment: @7vies: Added the answer to that question to my answer.

Comment: Search-and-replace looks like a very ugly way of doing it, initially using a typedef or even a macro looks better to me :\ Is what you are suggesting really the best practice, or just one of the ways of doing it?

Comment: @7vies: Yes, those both could work.  Though they basically just narrow down where the search and replace has to happen.  :-)  A macros would let you just change the token `auto_ptr` to whatever you wanted.  That would probably be good enough for most purposes.

Comment: @Omnifarious: Sorry but I'm asking for the *best practice*, not for *a way* to do this, I already do know the different options and the problem is to choose.

Comment: @7vies: I don't think anybody has come up with any 'best-practices' involving the changeover.  There is very definitely a best practice when it comes to returning objects polymorphically when ownership transfer is implied, and I gave it.  But there are no best practices I'm aware of for how to handle changing from one to the other when C++0x arrives.  Personally, I'd prefer search and replace to a macro or typedef.